# How to perform transaction with GET and modifying data and SET operation in spring-redis?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I want to create some function like the one below.

```
val conn = redisTemplate.connectionFactory!!.connection

conn.multi()

val s = conn.commands().get(myKey)
val myInfo = Json.decodeFromString<MyInfo>(s)
myInfo.removeMember(someone)
conn.commands().set(myKey, Json.encodeToString(myInfo)

conn.exec()
```

But in spring-redis, to reduce network call, using GET in transaction returns null. 
If I use WATCH in redis I can do a similar thing. 
But the problem is, for example, If two clients request to the server and their data stores in same key, I have to give a fail response to one of them because some transaction will fail because of WATCH. 
If I can do GET and SET in one transaction, all of request will not fail if request are valid. 
so how to do this kind of thing in spring-redis? I'm using spring-data-redis 3.1.1